# how to detect Empty paragraph in Word Document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in C#4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, interop, office-interop

I want to detect Empty paragraphs in Word Document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
Suppose, if my word document have some empty paragraphs,then

Assume paragraph 3 is an empty paragraph...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para = wordDoc.Content.Paragraphs[3];
int cSent = para.Range.Sentences.Count;

for (int j = 1; j <= cSent; j++)
{
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range sent = para.Range.Sentences[j];
 MessageBox.Show("Sent lines :" + sent.Text.ToString());
}
```

Then empty paragraphs has taken the last sentence of the last non-empty paragraph.So, I can't able to detect empty paragraphs in my Word Document.

Is there a way to get Empty paragraph list?

Please Guide me to Get out of this problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first, you may need to iterate through all the headers and footers of all sections if you also want to look for empty paras in those headers/footers.

Second, something like this should work

```
for each p in Doc.Content.Paragraphs
    if (p.Range.End - p.Range.Start) > 1 then (The paragraph is not empty)
Next
```

You may need to play with that "1" number, because I can't recall where Word sets the start and end points, empty paragraphs may be 2 chars long from start to end, not just one.

You can also do things like

```
p.Range.Sentences.Count > 0
```

or

```
p.Range.Characters.Count > 0
```

But those techniques are typically slower than checking the start and end positions.

Comment: @Saravanan Please do not edit other people's answers, but add a comment.

Comment: @phihag, stackoverflow supports editing other people's answers.  If you don't want people editing answers then you should be using a traditional forum.  Read the FAQ about editing.

Comment: @Samuell Neff That comment was just a follow-up to the rejected edit by the OP who posted a reaction to the answer as an edit (It even started with `@drventure`, if memory serves). It's certainly fine to edit questions to correct mistakes, add new details or so