# How do I find the page number for a Word Paragraph?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to parse a Word document and the information I am looking for should be located on the first page only. Is there any way to get the page number for a paragraph?

```
foreach (Word.Paragraph p in document.Paragraphs)
{
    // pageNo = .....
    // if(pageNo == 1 && p.Range.Text.StartsWith("This")) { 
    //     /* do some processing with the paragraph */ 
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From this post [VSTO 2007: how do I determine the page and paragraph number of a Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865340/vsto-2007-how-do-i-determine-the-page-and-paragraph-number-of-a-range) i could see you could get Page number form a range

```
/// <summary>
    /// Determines the pagenumber of a range.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="range">The range to be located.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static int GetPageNumberOfRange(Word.Range range)
    {
        return (int)range.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber);
    }
```

And from this post, [how to detect Empty paragraph in Word Document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in C#4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215552/how-to-detect-empty-paragraph-in-word-document-using-microsoft-office-interop-wor) i am sure u could find the Range from the paragraph!

```
for each p in Doc.Content.Paragraphs
    if (p.Range.End - p.Range.Start) > 1 then (The paragraph is empty)
Next
```

you should have your solution combining both the answers, i bet!

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach (Word.Paragraph p in document.Paragraphs)
{
   int page = p.Range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber];
   Console.WriteLine(p.Range.Text + " is on page " + page);
}
```

Something like that might be what you're looking for.  Read up on the difference between wdActiveEndPageNumber and wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber to see which one suits your need.