# Using Word Interop, how does one tell if a table is going to span multiple pages?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

Is there any way to catch a break in the table in order to insert a "Continued on next page" row? I've tried checking each row to see if the HeaderFormat is -1 (as I set headers to repeat on subsequent pages), but that doesn't work. I suppose I could count rows and guestimate, but I'd rather have an exact point at which to insert the new row at the bottom of the table before it breaks onto another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097402/how-do-i-find-the-page-number-for-a-word-paragraph) post describes how to find the page number from a range. You can call this with the range of a row and check when the page changes. When the page changes go back a row index and add the "Continued..." text.